# How to use the split() method with some condition?

Tags: python-3.x

There is one condition where I have to split my string in the manner that all the alphabetic characters should stay as one unit and everything else should be separated like the example shown below.

**Example**:

```
Some_var='12/1/20 Balance Brought Forward 150,585.80'

output_var=['12/1/20','Balance Brought Forward','150,585.80']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use some regex to get over this.

```
Some_var = '12/1/20 Balance Brought Forward 150,585.80'
match = re.split(r"([0-9\s\\\/\.,-]+|[a-zA-Z\s\\\/\.,-]+)", Some_var)
print(match)
```

You will get some extra spaces but you can trim that and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

split isn't gonna cut it. You might wanna look into Regular Expressions (abbreviated regex) to accomplish this.

[Here's a link to the Python docs: re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

As for a pattern, you could try using something like this:

```
([0-9\s\\\/\.,-]+|[a-zA-Z\s\\\/\.,-]+)
```

then trim each part of the output.